# What do I need to know in preparing to rent a car for an international road trip in the EU [Prague->Munich->Innsbruck->Vienna->Budapest->Prague]

Tags: europe, car-rentals, road-trips

I am planning a road trip across 4 countries with a rental car from Prague. I plan to cover Munich, Innsbruck, Salzburg, Vienna, Budapest, Gyor along the way and come back to Prague to end my trip.

Do different car rental companies have different rules about driving their cars into foreign countries? Are there any restrictions on applied rental cars for border crossings ? I've read I might need to buy separate insurance if I want to take rental car to Eastern Europe; are the 4 countries mentioned here-in part of Central Europe or Eastern Europe and if I would require a separate insurance in this case ?

Comment: Likely all main car rental companies are alright with this kind of journey as well as most of the smaller ones in Prague. But best select one or a few and contact them. E-mail is always possible but many companies do now do social media as well.

Comment: You're asking several questions, some of them are offtopic, answers for the others must be looked for in the rental conditions.

Comment: you  just check their term and conditions. Some ask e.g. 40€ and you can drive in any country in west & central europe. Other ask up to 40€-50€ per country. It is not easy  to drive in Europe especially cities like vienna/prauge/budapest. Besides that you can't park everywhere. For example in Vienna (in most of the districts) you pay up to 8€ for 3 hours parking  on street & you can only park up to 3 hours. How you get  parking tickets is another story or you go for parking garage. If you  have never driven in Europe before, then don't take rental car.

Comment: This is not a price shopping question; nowhere is cost mentioned.

Comment: @phoog intuitive - price comes under rules.  So if he pays the fee, he can drive  any where according to thier (rental company) term and conditions. He don't need anything else like separate insurance .

Comment: @NRandhawa that may or may not be true, depending on the company, but in any event discussing the terms and conditions, even discussing that some services require extra fees, is not a shopping discussion.  This question could reasonably be restated as "what do I need to know in preparing to rent a car for an international road trip in the EU?"  Such a question is a perfect fit for the site.  The only offending sentence ("which company would be best suited...") has been modified; the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

- We cannot suggest specific companies on this board.
- Yes, there are restrictions, but they mostly apply going eastward. Going westward and then returning should be easier. Insurance requirements depend on the specific company.

Comment: "We cannot suggest specific companies on this board": why not?

Comment: @phoog, I thought that shopping for specific deals and itineraries was against the rules on the board (WANTA).

Comment: Price-shopping questions are not allowed, but that's about what may be asked, not about what answers may say.  Lots of people have made product recommendations, and in particular I've never seen anything suggesting that it is improper to discuss different companies' policies (for example, one airline offers optional unaccompanied minor service for 16-year-olds while another doesn't).

Comment: @phoog, note that the question has been closed by others, based on the shopping reasoning.

Comment: I understand that.  I also disagree that this is a shopping question, and I have voted to reopen it.